# Yii validate multiple instances of same model

Tags: php, yii

i have multiple instances of same model in one form (mainly for languages entries).

In actionCreate:

```
$model1 = new ContentCategoryNames();
$model2 = new ContentCategoryNames();
$model = new ContentCategory;

$this->performAjaxValidation([$model1, $model2]);
```

In view:

```
echo $form->labelEx($model1, '[1]name');
echo $form->textField($model1, '[1]name');
echo $form->error($model1, '[1]name');

echo $form->labelEx($model2, '[2]name');
echo $form->textField($model2, '[2]name');
echo $form->error($model2, '[2]name');
```

And it generates all fields with ids like `ContentCategoryNames_1_name`, `ContentCategoryNames_1_name_em_` and so on. This is fine, but when i try to make ajax validation, i get response: `{"ContentCategoryNames_name":["Name cannot be blank."]}` - without sequence number (it must be `"ContentCategoryNames_1_name":/*...*/`). What am i missing?

Taking steps from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/362/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-the-same-model-in-the-same-form/)

Comment: This isn't an answer but [the guide to tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table) has a different approach to saving multiple model instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer. Using `CActiveForm::validateTabular();` according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419377/how-to-validate-tabular-data-in-yii)